# Discord.PY Custom Commands - can you define multiple commands/functions in one file?

Tags: discord.py

Silly question, but in Discord PY are you able to define multiple custom commands or functions in one file? I am working on a few custom commands and just noticed that only the one defined first works, the others say command not found. They all work individually, just not when there are multiple commands defined. Is this format just wrong? Not getting any syntax errors and again it was just working until I added the Add/Remove Roles commands, or even just a Test command that does nothing..

Thanks!

My code looks something like this:

```
imports

define HelperFunctions:

APIInfo, etc

#start bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

@bot.command()

#define bot commands


async def TestCommand(params):
    do stuff

async def AddRoles(params):
    do stuff

async def RemoveRoles(params):
    do stuff

async def AddToList(params):
    do stuff



bot.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

bot.command() decorator should be used separately for every command.

https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py

```
#define bot commands

@bot.command()
async def TestCommand(params):
    do stuff

@bot.command()
async def AddRoles(params):
    do stuff

@bot.command()
async def RemoveRoles(params):
    do stuff

@bot.command()
async def AddToList(params):
    do stuff
```